# Issues with installing surge

Tags: reactjs, command-line, terminal, surge.sh

I was trying to install Surge in order to publish my project but my terminal gave me the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES`
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/surge
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/surge'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/surge'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/surge'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I am not sure what I need to do. I am the administrator of the computer and the command I ran was `npm install -g surge`. I am on Mac OS Monterey version 12.4

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac OS Monterey version 12.4

Comment: Try this `sudo npm install -g surge`

Comment: Ok now it's saying: 

`npm ERR! code ENOLOCK`
`npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.`
`npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only`
`npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file`

Comment: Try this `npm i --package-lock-only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me like this:

```
npm i --package-lock-only

npm cache clean --force


npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: @mushroom_clouds great :)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the command it says to.

`npm i --package-lock-only`

`npm audit fix --force`

Anytime it give you permission issues then use `sudo` at start!

Then it showed me 0 vulnerabilities. Anyway, ran again audit fix and again 0 vulnerabilities.